# How to validate for a empty field for a mobile no in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

How do I validate for a empty phone number field in a form in flutter without using any extra packages or dependencies?

Comment: What did you try so far? Why isn't the validation you are using on other text fields working? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I was trying through the validator function but the requirement was to do it using without using any extra package or dependency.So the best method was to do it with if else directly in the onPressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to check the conditions before printing/returning the values.
Check for the following conditions before printing/returning the values.
Pass the following conditions in the onPressed.

```
    if(value == null || value.length <10)
      print('Enter valid input');
    else
      print(value);
```